# Powershell form closing when starting script by shortcut

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script that adds information to a word template and creates multiple copies for different date-ranges. The script uses a GUI. The last part of the script looks like this:

```
#Hinzufügen der Werkeuge für die Erstellung von grafischen Oberflächen
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

#ermittlen des Skriptortes, damit die erstellten Vorlagen im richtigen Ordner abgelegt werden
$parent=(Get-Location).Path

#Pfad für temporäre Unterschriftendatei wird festgelegt
$imgTemp=$parent+"\temp.png"

#Zeichnen der gesamten Formularfläche
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Berichtsheft-Multiplikator'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(720,415)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

#Zeichnen der einzelnen Text- und Eingabefelder
#Textfeld für Nachname
$namelabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$namelabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$namelabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(95,20)
$namelabel.Text = 'Nachname:'
$form.Controls.Add($namelabel)

#Eingabefeld für Nachname
$textBoxname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,20)
$textBoxname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxname)

#Textfeld für Vorname
$vornamelabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$vornamelabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,45)
$vornamelabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$vornamelabel.Text = 'Vorname:'
$form.Controls.Add($vornamelabel)

#Eingabefeld für Vorname
$textBoxvorname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBoxvorname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,45)
$textBoxvorname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBoxvorname)

#Textfeld für erste Kalenderwoche
$erstekwlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$erstekwlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$erstekwlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$erstekwlabel.Text = 'von KW:'
$form.Controls.Add($erstekwlabel)

#Eingabefeld für erste Kalenderwoche
$erstekwtextbox = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
@(1..53) | ForEach-Object {[void] $erstekwtextbox.Items.Add($_)}
$erstekwtextbox.SelectedIndex = 0
$erstekwtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,70)
$erstekwtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$form.Controls.Add($erstekwtextbox)

#Textfeld für letzte Kalenderwoche
$letztekwlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$letztekwlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,95)
$letztekwlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$letztekwlabel.Text = 'bis KW:'
$form.Controls.Add($letztekwlabel)

#Eingabefeld für letzte Kalenderwoche
$letztekwtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
@(1..53) | ForEach-Object {[void] $letztekwtextbox.Items.Add($_)}
$letztekwtextbox.SelectedIndex = 0
$letztekwtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,95)
$letztekwtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$form.Controls.Add($letztekwtextbox)

#Textfeld für Jahr
$JahrLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$JahrLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$JahrLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$JahrLabel.Text = 'für Jahr:'
$form.Controls.Add($JahrLabel)

#Eingabefeld für Jahr
$jahrtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
@(2023..2099) | ForEach-Object {[void] $jahrtextbox.Items.Add($_)}
$jahrtextbox.SelectedIndex = 0
$jahrtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,120)
$jahrtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$form.Controls.Add($jahrtextbox)

#Textfeld für Ausbildungsjahr
$ausbildungsjahrlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ausbildungsjahrlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,145)
$ausbildungsjahrlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$ausbildungsjahrlabel.Text = 'Ausbildungsjahr:'
$form.Controls.Add($ausbildungsjahrlabel)

#Eingabefeld für Ausbildungsjahr
$ausbildungsjahrtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
@(1..4) | ForEach-Object {[void] $ausbildungsjahrtextbox.Items.Add($_)}
$ausbildungsjahrtextbox.SelectedIndex = 0
$ausbildungsjahrtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,145)
$ausbildungsjahrtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60,20)
$form.Controls.Add($ausbildungsjahrtextbox)

#Textfeld für Abteilung
$abteilunglabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$abteilunglabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,170)
$abteilunglabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$abteilunglabel.Text = 'Ggf. Abteilung:'
$form.Controls.Add($abteilunglabel)

#Eingabefeld für Abteilung
$abteilungtextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$abteilungtextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,170)
$abteilungtextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(490,20)
$form.Controls.Add($abteilungtextbox)

#Textfeld für Unterschrift
$unterschriftlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$unterschriftlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,195)
$unterschriftlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,20)
$unterschriftlabel.Text = 'Datei für Unterschrift:'
$form.Controls.Add($unterschriftlabel)

#Eingabefeld für Unterschrift
$unterschrifttextbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$unterschrifttextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,195)
$unterschrifttextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,20)
$form.Controls.Add($unterschrifttextbox)

#Button für Unterschrift
$unterschriftButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$unterschriftButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(560,195)
$unterschriftButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$unterschriftButton.Text = 'Datei Suchen'
#Wenn der Button geklickt wird, wird ein Dateibrowser geöffnet
$unterschriftButton.add_Click({
$DateiSuche = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    Multiselect = $false
    InitialDirectory = $parent
    Filter = 'JPG-Datei (*.jpg)|*.jpg'
}
#Wenn eine Datei ausgewählt und auf 'OK' geklickt wird, wird das Bild in eine Variable geschrieben, die einerseits im Formular
#aufgerufen wird, um das Bild anzuzeigen, andererseits in der Schleife zur Erstellung der Dateien abgerufen wird,
#um diese in die Datei einzufügen
if($DateiSuche.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK'){
    #in die Textbox der unterschrift wird der Dateipfad eingetragen
    $unterschrifttextbox.Text = $DateiSuche.FileName
    #Aus dem Pfad wird ein Bild-Objekt erstellt
    $img = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::Fromfile($unterschrifttextbox.Text)
    #Das Seitenverhältnis wird ausgerechnet, um die Datei an späterer Stelle proportional zu verkleinern
    [float]$imgprop= $img.Width/$img.Height
    #Die Breite des Bildes wird errechnet. Die Höhe des Bildes wird auf 100px festgelegt. Dadurch sieht es einerseits im Formular vernünftig aus, 
    #andererseits verschiebt sich nichts im Word-Dokument, sobald das Bild eingefügt wird
    [int32]$imgHeight=100
    [int32]$imgWidth=[math]::Round($imgHeight*$imgprop)
    #Ein neues Bild-Objekt wird erstellt. 
    $imgResizedObj= New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($img,$imgWidth,$imgHeight)
    #Das verkleinerte Bild wird zwischengespeichert
    $imgResizedObj.Save($imgTemp)
    #Eine Vorschaubox wird erstellt
    $vorschauBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    #Das Bild wird der oben erstellten Vorschaubox hinzugefügt
    $vorschauBox.Image = $imgResizedObj
    $vorschauBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,220)
    $vorschauBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($imgWidth,$imgHeight)
    $form.Controls.add($vorschauBox)
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($unterschriftButton)

#Textfeld für Vorschau
$vorschaulabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$vorschaulabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,250)
$vorschaulabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,20)
$vorschaulabel.Text = 'Vorschau:'
$form.Controls.Add($vorschaulabel)

#Button zum Erstellen der Formularvorlage
$erstellenButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$erstellenButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,325)
$erstellenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(580,20)
$erstellenButton.Text = 'Vorlagen erstellen'
#$erstellenButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $erstellenButton
$form.Controls.Add($erstellenButton)

#Button zum Schließen des Formulars
$schließenButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$schließenButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(600,325)
$schließenButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$schließenButton.Text = 'Schließen'
$schließenButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.AcceptButton = $schließenButton
$form.Controls.Add($schließenButton)

#Fenster wird im Vordergrund geöffnet
$form.Topmost = $true

Function VorlagenErstellen {
#Übertragen der Eingaben in Variablen
$namevoll=$textBoxname.Text + ', ' + $textBoxvorname.Text
[int32]$startwoche=$erstekwtextbox.Text
[int32]$endwoche=$letztekwtextbox.Text
[int32]$jahr=$jahrtextbox.Text
[string]$abteilung=$abteilungtextbox.Text
[string]$ausbildungsjahr=$ausbildungsjahrtextbox.Text
[string]$unterschriftpfad = $unterschrifttextbox.Text

#Definition der Datei- und Ordnerpfade
#Pfad für Ordner erstellen und Pfad der Vorlage festlegen
$ordner= $parent+"\Berichtshefte nach KW"
$vorlage = $parent+"\Vorlage.doc"
$jahresordner = $ordner + "\" + $jahr

#Funktion für die Ermittlung des Datums vom Montag der jeweiligen Woche
Function FirstDateOfWeek
{
param([int]$year, [int]$weekOfYear)

$jan1 = [DateTime]"$year-01-01"
$daysOffset = ([DayOfWeek]::Thursday - $jan1.DayOfWeek)

$firstThursday = $jan1.AddDays($daysOffset)
$calendar = ([CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).Calendar;

$firstWeek = $calendar.GetWeekOfYear($firstThursday, [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek, [DayOfWeek]::Monday)

$weekNum = $weekOfYear

if($firstweek -le 1) { $weekNum -= 1 }

$result = $firstThursday.AddDays($weekNum * 7)
return $result.AddDays(-3)
}

#Erstellen der Ordner
New-Item -Path $ordner -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Path $jahresordner -ItemType Directory

#Öffnen von Word im Hintergrund
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application 
$objWord.Visible = $false

#Loop zu Erstellung der einzelnen Vorlagen nach Kalenderwoche
for ($i=$startwoche;$i -le $endwoche;$i++)
{
#Vorangestellte Null für einstellige Kalenderwochen
$kalenderwoche=$i.ToString().PadLeft(2,"0")
#Dateiname wird festgelegt
$output = $ordner + "\" +$jahr+"\Berichtsheft_" + $jahr + "_KW" + $kalenderwoche + ".doc"
#Vorlage wird kopiert
copy-item $vorlage $output
#Funktion FirstDateOfWeek wird aufgerufen und Ergebnis in Variable gespeichert
$datummo= FirstDateOfWeek -year $jahr -weekOfYear $i
#Datum wird in String umgewandelt und in Variable gespeichert
$datummontag=$datummo.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
#Sechs Tage werden hinzugefügt, um Datum des Sonntags zu ermitteln
$datumso=$datummo.AddDays(6)
#Ebd. wird in String umgewandelt
$datumsonntag=$datumso.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
#Vier Tage werden hinzugefügt, um Datum des Freitags zu ermitteln
$datumfr=$datummo.AddDays(4)
#Ebd. wird in String umgewandelt
$datumfreitag=$datumfr.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
#Kopie der Vorlage der jeweiligen Kalenderwoche wird geöffnet
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($output)
#Objekte werden erstellt, die auf jeweilige Textmarke zugreifen und Information wird eingefügt
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“von”).Range
$objRange.Text = $datummontag
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“bis”).Range
$objRange.Text = $datumsonntag
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“name”).Range
$objRange.Text = $namevoll
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“jahr”).Range
$objRange.Text = $ausbildungsjahr
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“abteilung”).Range
$objRange.Text = $abteilung
$objRange = $objDoc.Bookmarks(“datumunter”).Range
$objRange.Text = $datumfreitag
$imgloc = $objDoc.ActiveWindow
if (Test-Path $imgTemp) {$imgloc.Selection.GoTo(-1,0,0,$objDoc.Bookmarks.item("unterschrift"))
$imgloc.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture($imgTemp)} else {}
#Datei wird gespeichert
$objDoc.Save()
#Datei wird geschlossen
$objDoc.Close()
}
#Excel wird geschlossen
$objWord.Quit()

#Temporäre Unterschriftendatei wird gelöscht
if (Test-Path $imgTemp) {Remove-Item -Path $imgTemp}

#Garbage-Collector wird durchlaufen gelassen
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

#Excel wird zur Löschung aus RAM freigegeben
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objDoc)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
}

#Wenn Button zur Erstellung der Formularvolagen geklickt wird, startet folgender Code
$erstellenButton.Add_Click({
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty([string]$unterschrifttextbox.Text)) {
            $unterschriftFehltBox=[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Vorlagen ohne Unterschrift erstellen?','Sicher?','YesNo')
            switch ($unterschriftFehltBox){ 
                'Yes' {&VorlagenErstellen}
                'No'{
                }
            }
        } else {
            &VorlagenErstellen
        }
    })

$form.showDialog() |Out-Null
```

So, if i click the $erstellenButton a code start that checks if the textbox containing a path to an image file is empty. If its empty you will get a messagebox asking if you are sure to proceed. If you klick 'No', the messagebox should disappear so that you can add a filepath. If you klick yes the word-files will be created. If there already is a path in the textbox the word-files will be created, too.

Now when i run the script from inside powershell everything runs fine, except the whole form closes when i klick "No" in the message box.

If i call the script by shortcut, the whole form closes when i try to klick the $erstellenButton when $unterschrifttextbox is empty, not even showing an imagebox.

Any ideas how to fix these things?

Edit: i also added a check that looks for the file in $unterschrifttextbox. If there is no file, the script will not try to add the image.

Comment: You're gonna need to show us some more code if you want help with the form closing on clicking 'No'. For the shortcut problem: you forgot to post the shortcut details - what's the program path and exact arguments in the shortcut file?

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File "Autocopy_GUI.ps1"`

I found the culprit already though: I gave the $createButton the OK-property. Now the form is not closing, but there is still no messagebox showing up. I can post the whole code if neccessary, but i gave the variables german names and translated them for this post, so please dont be confused.

Comment: I got form to display by changing following : $results = $DateiSuche.ShowDialog();
if($results -eq 'OK'){

Comment: The form itself is showing up, but there is no MessageBox showing when i click $erstellenButton when $unterschrifttextbox.Text is empty

Comment: Add debug messages like : Write-Host "Got Here"  to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I had to add Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework. Now it works, but the whole form resizes when i click $erstellenButton when $unterschrifttextbox is empty. I'm very thankful though, you both helped me to add the last features! :)